# Determining if string is inside Text Content or part of attributes

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing

I am trying to come up with an algorithm that identififies if a string is part of the text content of an element or is it part of the element attributes.

For example:

```
  <a class="tag tag-red-dark" href="/keywords?q=PARTOFATTRIBUTE"> Found TEXTCONTENT </a>
```

If you perform regex on `TEXTCONTENT` or `PARTOFATTRIBUTE`, you can run this algorithm to check if they are part of the text or part of the attributes:

```
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(html, @"(?i)TEXTCONTENT");
    for (int i = matches.Count-1; i >= 0 ; i--){
      Match m = matches[i];

      int currentIndex = m.Index;
      bool isTextContent = false;
      while (html[currentIndex] != '<'){
        currentIndex--;
        if (html[currentIndex] == '>'){ // text is placed between > and <
          isTextContent = true;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (isTextContent){
        // do something with text content
      }else{
        // do something with attribute
      }
    }
```

But the algorithm is fragile. If your html looks like this:

```
  <a class="tag tag-red-dark" title="a>b" href="/keywords?q=PARTOFATTRIBUTE"> Found TEXTCONTENT </a>
```

PARTOFATTRIBUTE will be recognized as text, which is not.

Moreover, you could also have text with < in it, which makes the algorithm think that it found attribute:

```
  <a class="tag tag-red-dark" title="a>b" href="/keywords?q=PARTOFATTRIBUTE"> < Found TEXTCONTENT </a>
```

Placing <  in text without escaping is invalid html which i would like to handle. Placing > in attributes is on the other hand valid.  Is it possible to determine if the selected string is part of attributes of text content solely based on the environment in which it is placed?

Comment: An idea: You can introduce a method called IsValidElement() and then for each starting and ending tag check whether the element is valid. If it is not valid then you look for the next ending tag. I will also suggest you to come up with a pseudocode first rather than code itself.

Comment: You could use `HtmlAgilityPack` or some other 3rd party library that parses Html and then check all elements with custom validation logic

Comment: HTMLAgilityPack is extremly slow compared to manually walking over the html. In my tests, it takes up to 50ms to build the tree where as Regex takes less than 1ms. Also it doesn't offer functionality to simply replace the text content. All it can to is replace Node with newly created one.

Answer (score 0):

HtmlAgilityPack is not slow you do not have to parse the entire page just the A tag.  Since you probably already parsed the a tags from your html.  Just pass in only the the Html that you need parsed.

```
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml("<a class=\"tag tag - red - dark\" title=\"a > b\" href=\" / keywords ? q = PARTOFATTRIBUTE\"> < Found TEXTCONTENT </a>");

        if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes[0].InnerHtml.Contains("TEXTCONTENT"))
        {
            // do something with text content
        }

        if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["href"].Value.Contains("PARTOFATTRIBUTE"))
        {
            // do something with attribute
        }
```